# how can i keep UIAccelerometer object?

Tags: iphone, scope, singleton

i'm studying ios programming. but i have a problem that is UIAccelerometer.

here's code first.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
UIAccelerometer *accelerometer = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
accelerometer.delegate = self;
accelerometer.updateInterval =  kUpdateInterval;
[super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer 
    didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {

[(BallView *)self.view setAcceleration:acceleration];
[(BallView *)self.view draw];
}
```

first question is viewDidLoad, i use a method that is sharedAccelerometer

and it returns a shared object for a system.

when viewDidLoad is ended, does not local variable,accelerometer, disappear??

i think that when i get a accelerometer object, and it's gone.

because viewDidLoad is ended, and i don't have a instance variable about that.

that's just local variable.

second is delegate method.

i say, accelerometer.deleate = self in viewDidLoad.

but i don't have a instance variable about accelerometer, so

how that method is called, when viewDidLoad is ended?

i really don't understand about how can i keep UIAccelerometer object.

please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer]` will always return the same accelerometer object (a [singleton](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?SingletonDesignPattern)), so you can use it anywhere.

Comment: thank you for answering. but i still don't understand. and yeah, it's a singleton. but i think i say sharedAcceleometer, that's the object created by singleton. but i think that when i want to use it, i have to point the object. because when viewDidLoad is ended, the object is still existed, but i lost the pointer so i can't use it. am i wrong?

Comment: You lose the pointer, yes, but if you call `[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer]` again you will get the same pointer.

Comment: thank you and here's the last question. i don't have to release that object in dealloc? delegate method, have two argument, one is accelerometer, and other is acceleration, in this code second argument, acceleration is release in BallView class. but the first thing, accelerometer is never released, it is right? or i have to release that in dealloc?

Comment: No, since `-sharedAccelerometer` returns an autoreleased object, you never have to release it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a `UIAccelerometer` property in your header file

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIAccelerometer accelerometer;
```

And you can then assign it in your `viewDidLoad` like this:

```
*accelerometer = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
```

Now you can access the accelerometer by `self.accelerometer`

Special case here:

Yes, once the `viewDidLoad` is done, the accelerometer object you created won't be accessible anymore. - THOUGH you can always call it from the `[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer]` singleton provider. (It will always return the same object)

The delegate handles calls/events of a certain object during it's lifetime.

Thus you could also use this statement - Make sure you conform to the `UIAccelerometerDelegate` Protocol for this:

`[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer].delegate = self`

Answer (score 0):

When you set the delegate of an object, you increment it's retain count by one. So even though you have the local variable `accelerometer`, which goes out of scope once the function returns, the class which the `UIAccelerometer` object was set as the delegate will retain it until that class reaches a retain count of zero.

The best method to really do this if you want to keep a reference to the object is to at the top of your class create an empty category and declare an ivar for your accelerator in there.

```
@interface myClassWithUIAccelerator()
{
    UIAccelerator *accelerator;
}
@end
```

...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    accelerometer = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
    accelerometer.delegate = self;
    accelerometer.updateInterval =  kUpdateInterval;
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```